# Python: Get n possible minimum sets of m values from the list

Tags: python, list, combinatorics

There is given a dictionary with few points with their distance where key - name of the point, and value - it's distance, i.e.

```
points_dict = {"a": 18, "b": 7, "c": 15, "d": 22, "e": 33, "f": 5}
```

The question is to find f.e. **6** shortest routes in order for **3** different points from the dict, so **6** lowest sums of **3** different values from given dict values in order.

I tried to do this in following way - get distances into a list, then sort it to:

```
example_list = [5, 7, 15, 18, 22, 33]
```

And then just get first 6 combinations, so:

> 1. 5+7+15
> 2. 5+7+18
> 3. 5+7+22
> 4. 5+7+33
> 5. 7+15+18

and so on...

But as you can see, it isn't right, because 4. `5+7+33 = 45` while  5. `7+15+18 = 40`, so it should be before it, as lowest sum, so "shortest" distance. I can't figure out any algorithm and solution to deal with this. Any tips how it can be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you start at a certain point? It looks to me this is a variant of the *subset sum* problem, where you can then "harvest" combinations at the end that are minimal. Or you could use a variant of Dijkstra's algorithm to generate minimal combinations after 3 "hops".

Comment: the fact that it is not an *explicit* graph does not mean you can not "represent" it as a graph. You can draw a graph with the above information with the given data.

Comment: well yes, it look similar to it, but it it's not a graph. I can't properly describe it because of my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the `example_list = [5, 7, 15, 18, 22, 33]`, you can use this one liner to get the list of combination by 3 elements sorted by their sum:

```
from itertools import combinations

sorted(list(combinations(example_list, 3)),key=sum)

#=> [(5, 7, 15), (5, 7, 18), (5, 7, 22), (5, 15, 18), (7, 15, 18), (5, 15, 22), (7, 15, 22), (5, 7, 33), (5, 18, 22), (7, 18, 22), (5, 15, 33), (7, 15, 33), (15, 18, 22), (5, 18, 33), (7, 18, 33), (5, 22, 33), (7, 22, 33), (15, 18, 33), (15, 22, 33), (18, 22, 33)]
```

Then pick the first six.

If you want also to keep track of the original keys:

```
tmp_list = [[k, v] for k, v in points_dict.items()]
sorted(list(combinations(tmp_list, 3)), key = lambda x: sum(i[1] for i in x) )[0:6]

#=> [(['c', 15], ['b', 7], ['f', 5]), (['a', 18], ['b', 7], ['f', 5]), (['b', 7], ['d', 22], ['f', 5]), (['a', 18], ['c', 15], ['f', 5]), (['a', 18], ['c', 15], ['b', 7]), (['c', 15], ['d', 22], ['f', 5])]
```

Comment: Thanks, that exactly what was needed!
Yes, keys are also needed (to display in result's output), but i managed to get them later from dict by value, because it needed to be formated in some specific way in print out

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [powerset recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes) from itertools, combine it with [collection.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and use only those with 3 element tuples. This will overproduce data though - its not optimal if you have *huge* dictionaries:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
from collections import defaultdict

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)

    # you can hardcode your 3-tuples here as well and eliminate lots of data and filtering
    # return combinations(s, 3)

    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))


points_dict = {"a": 18, "b": 7, "c": 15, "d": 22, "e": 33, "f": 5}

d = defaultdict(list)
for s in powerset(points_dict.values()):
    if len(s) == 3:
        d[sum(s)].append(s) 

sor = sorted(d)
for s in sor:
    print(s, d[s])
```

Output:

```
27 [(7, 15, 5)]
30 [(18, 7, 5)]
34 [(7, 22, 5)]
38 [(18, 15, 5)]
40 [(18, 7, 15)]
42 [(15, 22, 5)]
44 [(7, 15, 22)]
45 [(18, 22, 5), (7, 33, 5)]
47 [(18, 7, 22)]
53 [(15, 33, 5)]
55 [(18, 15, 22), (7, 15, 33)]
56 [(18, 33, 5)]
58 [(18, 7, 33)]
60 [(22, 33, 5)]
62 [(7, 22, 33)]
66 [(18, 15, 33)]
70 [(15, 22, 33)]
73 [(18, 22, 33)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the powerset receip from itertools, combine it with colleciton.defaultdict and use only those with 3 element tuples:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

# https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))


points_dict = {"a": 18, "b": 7, "c": 15, "d": 22, "e": 33, "f": 5}
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for s in powerset(points_dict.values()):
    if len(s) == 3:
        d[sum(s)].append(s) 

sor = sorted(d)
for s in sor:
    print(s, d[s])
```

Output:

```
27 [(7, 15, 5)]
30 [(18, 7, 5)]
34 [(7, 22, 5)]
38 [(18, 15, 5)]
40 [(18, 7, 15)]
42 [(15, 22, 5)]
44 [(7, 15, 22)]
45 [(18, 22, 5), (7, 33, 5)]
47 [(18, 7, 22)]
53 [(15, 33, 5)]
55 [(18, 15, 22), (7, 15, 33)]
56 [(18, 33, 5)]
58 [(18, 7, 33)]
60 [(22, 33, 5)]
62 [(7, 22, 33)]
66 [(18, 15, 33)]
70 [(15, 22, 33)]
73 [(18, 22, 33)]
```